# Queue arrangement Problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recursion

Our Teacher gave us the question as follows:

> $10$ people ( *five* of them, let's call them group $A$, have *$5$-valued* coin each and the *other five*, group B, have *$10$-valued* coin each ) enter a ticket counter in a queue for purchasing *tickets costing $5$-value*. *The Ticket Manager has no money initially*. In how many ways can the people entering, be arranged such that all of them will be able to get one ticket?

I notice each step of assigning people their position in the queue gets more complex than previous step, so it could be solved through recursion. But I am noobie at recursive questions, so couldn't proceed. I could only say that number of $A's \geq$  number of $B's$ at every step. But how to interpret this in terms of a recursion relation?

NOTE:- $5$-value means something like $₹5$ or $\$5$. I didn't want to use a particular denomination.

Comment: This is a [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Yes, Wiki explains about Dyck words which is the exact case. But if number of A's and B's are different, then?

Comment: If $A > B$, you may be able to apply [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, That helped, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a queue arrangement problem. See
Case -1 first place all the people, having rs 5 value coin, which can be done in 5!=120 ways, after them place all people having rs 10 value coin, which can be done again in 5!=120 ,ways. So entire queue can be arranged in 120**120=14400,ways. Now look into, that first 5 will contribute a total of rs 25 to the ticket manager,having 5 coins having rs 5 value, so that he may return each one rs 5 ,by taking rs 10 value, for each ticket ,from next having rs 10 value coin each.
Case -2 you may place persons having rs 5 and rs 10 value coins, alternatively,,so that first ticket manager get rs 5 for, selling a ticket, and then this  rs 5, can be used for returning rs 5 , to the next person who gave rs 10 , for a ticket.
Thus this arrangement can be made in 5!**5!=120**120=14400 , ways.
Case -3 place two people having 5 value coins, then place two people having 10 value coin ,then place remaining 3 having 5 value coin ,and in the last place all 3 remaining 10 value coins, and see objective of the situation is satisfied.
This can be done in 5C2**2!**5C2**2!**3!**3=144 00 ways.
Case -4 first place 3with 5 value coins, then place 3 having 10 value coin, then place 2 remaing, with 5 value coins, and in last place remaining 2 with 10 ,value coin.
Again objective of the problem is fulfilled.
This can be done in 5C3**3!**5C3**3!**2!**2!=144 00 ways.
Thus total number of arrangements = 4**14400=57600.ways.

Comment: Answer is 604800. You have ignored many cases, also this Question isn't meant to be solved by cases...that will take a lot of effort and precision